# How to add custom chip enable (reset) signal to chip?

Tags: solid-state-relay, reset

I use in my schema I2C chip that not have pin for hardware reset of chip. You just have power pins VCC, GND or signal pins. I would like to add trigger switch which reset (shortly break power to chip) and such way produce HW reset of the chip.

I made it in my design but without success. I interrupted the GND pin with solid state relay. But the break the GND power signal did not reset the chip.

[image: SSR reset chip]

Do you made it in your design?

IC power supply:
[image: Chip power supply]

X6 is circuit breaker, currently off.

Comment: You can just cut power to the IC(High side switch, i.e. VCC) with a P FET, also making sure that it also cant get power through the diodes in the I/Os.

Comment: Disconnecting ground is usually the worst idea. But if you would be more specific, it might help. What I2C chip you are trying to reset, and what other connections the I2C chip has? Also, it would help to know why you need to reset it, and why did you choose to make it by disconnecting power to it, and why the ground? Please add the information to your question. Also, be more specific, do you want to know why your solution does not work and how to fix it, or just asking how other people have done it? Because, in my opinion, there is usually no reason to cut power to I2C chips to reset them.

Comment: Hello Justme. The chip is EMC2301 (Fan controller with a PWM fan driver). In some situations chip can be set to status from which only hardware reset is the way to restore it. The reset by ground was probably main mistake because chip is in unstable mode but not in reset phase. It should be interrupted the power of the chip. In next test I planned to do it by power pin. I used ssr because I wanted to galvanic separated the schemas. Trigger was at VDD power and chip at VCC power. I used GND interruption to minimize voltage lose at power pin of the switch.

Comment: Thanks Wesley for advice. Will be there also any power loses at the P FET? VCC is the 3.3V

Comment: Disconnecting VCC supply may not help either, as the chip may receive enough power via other IO pins, unless they are guaranteed to be at 0V too. Please understand that you might have an XY problem. The chip hangs because there is problem X. But because Y (cutting power) solves the problem X, you are trying to solve how to implement Y. It might be more fruitful to solve why it hangs and remove that problem from happening, instead of implementing an expensive solution to work around the issue when it has already happened. Show the connections of the fan controller, maybe there is an error.

Comment: @MarianMinar:  Are you using the watchdog function?

Comment: The diagram shows only connections of the left half of the chip, and, it does not show where they are connected and how. Also, just to mention, the SSR does not perform any galvanic separation of anything, as both sides are ground referenced anyway.

Comment: JRE, no I am not. Just manually HW reset chip if needed.

Comment: If you cut the positive supply rail you must also guarantee that the chip **will not** get any positive-voltage signals from any pins under **any circumstances**. Because, absolute maximum ratings define the maximum pin voltages for signal pins w.r.t. the supply voltage (e.g. VDD+0.2), so when the VDD = 0 then none of the pins should see a positive voltage. And there's a risk of that the chip can get energised through clamping/protection diodes (if any) on these pins.

Comment: Justme. Ok thanks about SSR info. Hmm... Right side of the schema. ALERT pin is off. PWM is output pin. TACH is input pin and through resistance bridges connected to GND. CLK pin is directly connected to GND. When I switch off GND pin still there is GND connection through the CLK pin or through resistor at TACH pin.

Comment: Rohan, thanks for advice. I will let you know after my next test.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution, thanks Justme for their attention and advice. When I changed GND to GND_TRIG signal at serveral points it works as expected. After button triggered I2C chip is restarted.

[image]